# Spark Scala FoldLeft Performance slowness

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, foldleft, scd2

Hi I am trying to do a scdtype2 update in dataframe having 280 columns.

```
val newYRecs = stgDF.columns
                .foldLeft(joinedDF)
                  {(tempDF,colName) => 
                      tempDF.withColumn("new_" + colName, when(col("stg." + colName).isNull, col("tgt."+ colName)).otherwise(col("stg."  + colName))).drop(col("stg." + colName)).drop(col("tgt." + colName)).withColumnRenamed("new_" + colName,colName)
```

This is taking 8 minutes alone to execute. Is there any way this can be optimized?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015) article, it seems that `withColumn` has a hidden cost of the Catalyst optimizer that hampers performance when used on many columns. I would try using the proposed workaround and doing something like this (Also while you're at it, you can make your code cleaner with `coalesce`):

```
val newYRecs = joinedDF.select(stgDF.columns.map{ colName =>
      coalesce(col("stg." + colName), col("tgt."+ colName)) as colName
}: _*)
```